# Does -localizedDescription of NSError return the actual localized string, or does it return a key for NSLocalizedString?

Tags: iphone

Must I do something like this?

```
NSString *errorDescription = [error localizedDescription];
NSString *errorInfoStr = NSLocalizedString(errorDescription, nil);
```

Or do I use NSLocalizedString already when populating the userInfo dictionary with the NSLocalizedDescriptionKey key and value? So the value for that is not actually a key for NSLocalizedString, but it is the actual localized string ready to show up on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the docs say

> Returns a string containing the localized description of the error.

So the method should return a string that is ready to be displayed to the user. The NSError objects returned by the iPhone SDK functions contain human-readable strings so you should do the same.

If you are wanting to localize your own error messages then you should use `NSLocalizedString` when constructing the NSError (i.e. when setting the value of the `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` key in userInfo).